# Template problem when I want to call different function according to template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want to create a little library for calculating distances between point and lines, in both spherical and flat coordiantes (it's part of a more complex problem).

I want to follow a template approach in order to specify which function it should be called, after reading the related [Boost Geometry Page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/design.html).

If I have two structs, `Point2D` and `Line2D`, I want to calcuate their distances (point to point, point to line, line to line etc).

Obviously I need to create a function for every case (I don't care for now the fact that distance calculus is commutative) so I create for example a `GetPoint2DPoint2DFlatDistance` for distances between points in flat coordinates, `GetPoint2DPoint2DSphericalDistance` for calculating distance between points in spherical coordinates, `GetPoint2DPLine2DFlatDistance` for calculating distance between point and line in flat coordinates and so on.

I don't want to remember them all, and I want to use a uniform way for calling functions. The final user should be able to call something like `double distance = GetDistance<FlatMethod>(s1, s2)`, and it should work regardless the type of `s1` and `s2`, if a function is available for it.

I've tried to reproduce the tag mechanism defined in the boost page, but I'm not be able to solve the problem.

Maybe there can be more efficient ways to achieve the same result, but note that this is an example as a part of a more complex design, so using `GetDistance<FlatMethod>(s1, s2)` even if it's not the best way to do it, it's the way that we need. If it's not possible we'll change the design, but I'd like to maintain this signature for calculating distances.

This is my code, but I obtain a compilation error. What I'm doing wrong?

BTW, I'm using C++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// Define structures used in distance functions

struct Point2D {
  double x;
  double y;
};

struct Line2D {
  Point2D start;
  Point2D end;
};

// Define functions for calculating distances

double GetPoint2DPoint2DFlatDistance(const Point2D& p1, const Point2D& p2) {
  return sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.y - p2.y));
}

double GetPoint2DPLine2DFlatDistance(const Point2D& p1, const Line2D& l2) {
  return 0.0; // Just to have the function
}

double GetPoint2DPoint2DSphericalDistance(const Point2D& p1, const Point2D& p2) {
  // WRONG! Just to have a distance function in spherical coordinates
  return (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.y - p2.y);
}

// Define structure traits

struct Point2DTag{};
struct Line2DTag {};

namespace Traits {

template <typename G>
struct Tag {};

template <>
struct Tag<Point2D> {
  typedef Point2DTag Type;
};

template <>
struct Tag<Line2D> {
  typedef Line2DTag Type;
};

} // namespace Traits

// Define type of distances for performing calculus

struct FlatMethod {};
struct SphericalMethod {};

// Define the dispatcher that, according to argument type, call the right
// function for calculating distance. The purpose is to calculate distance for
// every shape combination with (in case of flat method)
//
// Point2D p1;
// Point2D p2;
// double distance = Get2DDistance<FlatMethod>(p1, p2);

template<typename S1, typename S2, typename Method>
double Get2DDistance(const S1& s1, const S2& s2) {
  using Traits::Tag;
  return Dispatch::GetDistance2D<
    typename Tag<S1>::Type,
    typename Tag<S2>::Type,
    S1,
    S2,
    Method>::apply<Method>(s1, s2);
};

namespace Dispatch {
template <typename Tag1, typename Tag2, typename S1, typename S2, typename Method >
struct GetDistance2D
{};

template <typename S1, typename S2>
struct GetDistance2D <Point2DTag, Point2DTag, S1, S2, FlatMethod> {
  static double apply<FlatMethod>(const S1& s1, const S2& s2) {
    return GetPoint2DPoint2DFlatDistance(s1, s2);
  }
};

template <typename S1, typename S2>
struct GetDistance2D <Point2DTag, Line2DTag, S1, S2, FlatMethod> {
  static double apply<FlatMethod>(const S1& s1, const S2& s2) {
    return GetPoint2DPoint2DFlatDistance(s1, s2);
  }
};

template <typename S1, typename S2>
struct GetDistance2D <Point2DTag, Point2DTag, S1, S2, SphericalMethod> {
  static double apply<SphericalMethod>(const S1& s1, const S2& s2) {
    return GetPoint2DPoint2DSphericalDistance(s1, s2);
  }
};

} // namespace Dispatch


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Point2D p1{2.3, 4.4};
  Point2D p2{2.5, 9.5};
  Line2D line;

  double pointDistance = Get2DDistance<FlatMethod>(p1, p2);
  std::cout << "Point distance is " << pointDistance << std::endl;
  double pointLineDistance = Get2DDistance<FlatMethod>(p1, line);
  std::cout << "Point Line distance is " << pointLineDistance << std::endl;
  double spointDistance = Get2DDistance<SphericalMethod>(p1, p2);
  std::cout << "Spherical point distance is " << spointDistance << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please paste the exact text of the error message.

Comment: This seems overcomplicated. Why not just create an overload set for `flat_distance` and `spherical_distance` to start with, so that you only need to toggle on whether `T` is the specified tag? If it's an overload set, you don't even necessarily need the `T` dispatching, you can just call `flat_distance` or `spherical_distance` between two objects and boom -- result

Comment: Use `std::hypot()` to get the distance between two 2D point.

Comment: As I've said, it's only an example, real things are more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code fails is because you have defined the dispatching function to be:

```cpp
template<typename S1, typename S2, typename Method>
double Get2DDistance(const S1& s1, const S2& s2)
```

Where you want to deduce `S1` and `S2`, but explicitly specify `Method`. When you explicitly specify `template` parameters, it is always done left-to-right (just like a function call). So if you want `Method` to be explicitly specified by the user, you will need to change it to:

```cpp
template<typename Method, typename S1, typename S2>
double Get2DDistance(const S1& s1, const S2& s2)
```

---

That said: the tag-based dispatching is rather unnecessary if you're working in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). You should have access to `if constexpr` now, which allows you to statically branch  on things like type-information -- something previously only possible with tag-dispatching.

This could be done without all the extra types like:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// ...

template <typename Tag, typename S1, typename S2>
double Get2DDistance(const S1& s1, const S2& s2) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Tag,FlatMethod>) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<S1,Point2D> && std::is_same_v<S1,Point2D>) {
            return GetPoint2DPoint2DFlatDistance(s1, s2);
        } else if constexpr (...) {
           ...
        }
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Tag,SphericalMethod>) {
        ...
    }

};
```

However, this will be a lot of separate conditions to check now since you need to check for all possible combinations.

If you want to make this much easier on yourself, you should consider not naming each of these functions uniquely -- and instead making them an *overload set*. For example:

```cpp
double flatDistance(const Point2D& p1, const Point2D& p2);
double flatDistance(const Point2D& p, const Line2D& l);
double flatDistance(const Line2D& l, const Point2D& p);
double flatDistance(const Line2D& l1, const Line2D& l2);


double sphericalDistance(const Point2D& p1, const Point2D& p2);
double sphericalDistance(const Point2D& p, const Line2D& l);
double sphericalDistance(const Line2D& l, const Point2D& p);
double sphericalDistance(const Line2D& l1, const Line2D& l2);
```

If you do this, your `Get2DDistance` function can be massively simplified to just:

```cpp
template <typename Tag, typename S1, typename S2>
double Get2DDistance(const S1& s1, const S2& s2) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Tag,FlatMethod>) {
        return flatDistance(s1, s2);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Tag,SphericalMethod>) {
        return sphericalDistance(s1, s2);
    }
};
```

Realistically at this point, the tag itself isn't even necessary -- and you could also just allow your callers to freely call `flatDistance` or `sphericalDistance` to decide flat or spherical computations.

Comment: It seems a far better solution, thanks. For design reason that does not depend only on me there's the need of the tag, so the solution seems pretty good.